# Why MQTT is called as "light weight" messaging protocol?

Tags: networking, protocols, messaging, mqtt, tcp

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) and [Mqtt.org](http://mqtt.org/),

> MQTT is a machine-to-machine (M2M)/"Internet of Things" connectivity protocol. It was designed as an **extremely lightweight** publish/subscribe messaging transport.

In comparison with other TCP/IP or socket based protocols, what makes MQTT "extremely light-weighted"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The protocol overhead of MQTT is extremely small, the smallest packet has only 2 bytes overhead. The payload-to-overhead ratio is typically extremely good. It's also a binary protocol which reduces the overhead on the wire a lot.

An older but good blog post about the lightweightness can be found here: http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/1217

If you are interested in protocol details, check out this extensive blog post series: http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-essentials-wrap-up/